# Program crashing randomly due to free() call in multiple threads

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, free

I have a piece of code where I have something like :

```
int *mem_ptr;
.
.
if(mem_ptr)
{
    free(mem_ptr);
}
.
.
```

The application is multi-threaded. Sometimes, what happens is one thread passes the `if` check and then before `free()` context switch happens and another thread also passes the `if` check and also do the `free()`. Now when the control comes back to first thread it crashes at `free()` giving the error `Abort message: 'invalid address or address of corrupt block 0x40735cb0 passed to dlfree'`.

Other than mutex, is there a better way to handle this situation

PS : I am working on Android native binders in C++ and this piece of code is inside the `onTransact()` call.

Comment: Can't you use shared_ptr ? If not, implementing a ref-counted mechanism using atomic increments and decrements would be worth the time.

Comment: Arunmu's right - your logic is inherently broken not just because of potentially multiple frees, but also because one thread may free the pointed-to-memory while another thread continues to use it (not having made it to the `if` yet).  Jeegar's answer about making the `free(mem_ptr)` atomic isn't sufficient to get reliably working code.

Comment: make sure the mem is allocated via malloc

Answer (score 1):

If two or more threads are attempting to free/delete same memory then code as well as design is broken. While threading sync primitives would help, I would not use them either. There should be just one thread freeing up the memory. It should ideally be the one who has allocated the memory. If it is different, as in case of cross thread message passing, still only **one** target thread should delete the memory.

It's like saying one thread opens a file, and any thread will close it. It doesn't look good. Closure of file should be done by single thread, and not by multiple threads in contention.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1) `free` operation should be atomic. So use any mechanism like mutex, semaphore etc.

2) After `free()` call, explicitly update your pointer to `NULL`. So in second thread it will not give in `if()`

Please note: `free()` call after feering memory will not assign NULL to your pointer.

Comment: That's the whole point. Even if I assign NULL, both threads have entered the checks.... so it won't help in some cases. It depends where the context switch happens. Mutex is definitely the solution. That's what I wrote in my question.

Comment: @InsaneCoder, no, `free` from `NULL` pointer works well. So there is no problem if few threads came inside that block. But `free` and setting pointer to NULL have to be atomic.

Answer (score 0):

Because `free` from `NULL` works well, doing nothing, use that:

```
int *mem_ptr(NULL);
.
.
if(mem_ptr)
{
    //any multithreaded lock guard have to be here
    free(mem_ptr);
    mem_ptr = NULL;
}
```

So, only thing you have to care, is that operations `free` and setting pointer to `NULL` have to be atomic.

And that means stop all other threads from performing those operations until one didn't finished, that means using core sync objects.

Comment: The location of the lock should be _before_ the `if`. The code as suggested is a variation of the Double Checked Locking Pattern.

Comment: but what's a problem if second thread will enter `if`, then wait for first thread will release memory and set pointer to `NULL`, and then just call `free` from NULL, and rewrite pointer to `NULL`?

Comment: The problem is that calling `free(mem_ptr)` on the second thread isn't calling `free(NULL)`, it's calling `free(mem_ptr)`. The fact that you set `mem_ptr` to `NULL` on another thread is irrelevant when you haven't properly protected access to `mem_ptr`. Because you do an unprotected check of `if(mem_ptr)`, the compiler may assume that no other thread changes it. Putting the lock in the right place tells the compiler that `mem_ptr` is shared, other threads may write to it, and therefore it can only be put in a register within the scope of that lock.

Comment: @MSalters, just to be clean: so, you say, that compiler may optimize this part, and even if first thread changed value of `mem_ptr` to `NULL`, second thread after `mem_ptr` was changed to `NULL`, may work with it, keeping not-null value?

Comment: Yes, that's true. `mem_ptr` is either properly synchronized or it's not. You can't have variabes that "were improperly synchronized in the past, but now are properly synchronized again".

Comment: that's really strange. 
For example, I have thread, that sets global `int` value `a = 5` and starts second thread that change's it to 6, and wait for second thread to die. If this `int` was not protected, there is a chance, that second thread will work with it's own copy of `int`. And after second thread die, first use `int` with value 5??

Comment: At the start of a thread, variables are synchronized. See my previous comment " you cannot synchronize variables later on" so they obviously have to start synchronized. But the exit of a thread is not such a synchronization point, so **yes**, it indeed is possible that the first thread still sees `a==5`

Comment: It just blowing my mind that I need synchronize variable with itself. For example, `mem_ptr` variable is at address A. Both threads are working with address A, where stored value of `mem_ptr`. If one of threads will change value at address A, how that may happens, that second thread at address A will see old state AFTER it was changed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114120/discussion-between-msalters-and-arkady).

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the pointer to NULL as explained in the other answers... but this still does not guarantee success. Two threads may both get through and call free() one after another and then both assign to NULL after this....but too late since your program may well have crashed.

You need to use thread sync mechanisms here like a mutex:

```
std::mutex mtx;           // declare mutex for critical section
  :
  :
mtx.lock(); // only one thread will get inside here...
if(mem_ptr)
{
    //any multithreaded lock guard have to be here
    free(mem_ptr);
    mem_ptr = NULL;
}
mtx.unlock(); // release the mutex...
```